# best way to develop multi user database driven application. (C# wpf sql server replication)

Tags: c#, wpf, architecture, multi-user

we have a C# wpf based application and want it to be a multi user thingy now. database is ready for it. We have database replication say across 10 sites ...

which is the best architecture for converting this into a multi user application? this is a desktop application.

thank you.

Comment: What's stopping it from being a multi user application right now?

Comment: Can the users not connect to a single copy of the database somewhere? And is it necessary that they be able to work disconnected?

Comment: @ Fosco - dont have any proper architecture right now if many user want to work on same module/piece or something like that .. then how do i notify user that somebody else is working? or do you want to refresh the information .. data has changed .. something like that ...this is a desktop application ...

Comment: @DOK - example 10 geographically different places is US but all the databases are synced / replicated automatically

Comment: @ Brian Hooper - I wanted to do that .. but pardon my ignorance ,,, i never found button, link, anything to mark anything as answered ... can u pls help me here ... thanks in advance

Comment: @pskk, If you go look at the questions you have asked, you'll see answers under them. Next to each answer is a white checkmark, if you click it, the checkmark will turn green. This marks that answer as accepted.

Comment: @pskk so you dont even know how to use the site.. maybe you should post a question for that too...

Comment: @Luiscencio well before pointing you finger at me .. you could have also thought its a bad UI :) .... if the dumb me had problems .. then many other might have faced the same problem .. Ïts not intuitive" :) .. i bet  "Luiscencio" does not agree ...

Comment: @pskk @Brian Hooper We aren't always patient with new users. But with Brian's help, you've got the hang of it now. Welcome to the community.

Answer (score 1):

You have a C# WPF app talking to a database. That's as good an architecture for a multi-user application as you'll need. What you need now is to keep user concurrency in mind when you retrieve/update data. I'd stay away from replication as long as I could.

*An aside on your post... **do** be as specific as you can in your questions. Calling something a "multi user thingy" and over-using terminology such as "something like that" really doesn't help people to understand your problem - just my 2c.*

Comment: thnk u for the note .. we hv GUI layer ,data layer and a logic layer that binds these. There are many parts/modules in our product ...  to give you an analogy if our product is a about editing tree .. users can be working on trunk, branches, leaves fruits. i need read and write locks based on the working area

And this is in multiple geographic locations (example 10 sites). we use DB replication (ms sql server).. but its hard for me to assume that its the same data on all 10 ms sql databases all the time  and all the 10 databases have exactly the same data.  thank you guys for your help

Comment: Why not put your DB on a central server and expose it through a web service? That way you can manage locking/etc in one place and you don't need to be aware of that on the client? (just a thought).
If the comments/answers are helpful, feel free to vote me up :-)

Comment: thanks ... tht would wrk well if we had client server architecture. Since the nodes are distributed, centralized solution, i guess, is not the right choice